# Can't get Librosa to load

Tags: python, machine-learning, librosa

Playing around with Librosa, and I can't seem to get the line below to work without a bunch of errors popping up. Any idea what to do? I'm running Jupyter Notebook on Arch Linux. I've already tried installing Miniconda 3 instead, but to no avail.

```
y, sr = librosa.load("/home/brad/Downloads/Data/genres_original/blues/blues.00007.wav")
```

Here is the feedback Jupyter had for me. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated. Thank you!Jupyter feedback:

---

```
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[67], line 2
      1 # Importing 1 file
----> 2 y, sr = librosa.load("/home/brad/Downloads/Data/genres_original/blues/blues.00007.wav")
      4 print('y:', y)
      5 print('y shape:', np.shape(y), '\n')

File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lazy_loader/__init__.py:77, in attach.<locals>.__getattr__(name)
     75 submod_path = f"{package_name}.{attr_to_modules[name]}"
     76 submod = importlib.import_module(submod_path)
---> 77 attr = getattr(submod, name)
     79 # If the attribute lives in a file (module) with the same
     80 # name as the attribute, ensure that the attribute and *not*
     81 # the module is accessible on the package.
     82 if name == attr_to_modules[name]:

File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lazy_loader/__init__.py:76, in attach.<locals>.__getattr__(name)
     74 elif name in attr_to_modules:
     75     submod_path = f"{package_name}.{attr_to_modules[name]}"
---> 76     submod = importlib.import_module(submod_path)
     77     attr = getattr(submod, name)
     79     # If the attribute lives in a file (module) with the same
     80     # name as the attribute, ensure that the attribute and *not*
     81     # the module is accessible on the package.

File /usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    124             break
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py:17
     14 import soxr
     15 import lazy_loader as lazy
---> 17 from numba import jit, stencil, guvectorize
     18 from .fft import get_fftlib
     19 from .convert import frames_to_samples, time_to_samples

File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/__init__.py:42
     38 from numba.core.decorators import (cfunc, generated_jit, jit, njit, stencil,
     39                                    jit_module)
     41 # Re-export vectorize decorators and the thread layer querying function
---> 42 from numba.np.ufunc import (vectorize, guvectorize, threading_layer,
     43                             get_num_threads, set_num_threads,
     44                             set_parallel_chunksize, get_parallel_chunksize,
     45                             get_thread_id)
     47 # Re-export Numpy helpers
     48 from numba.np.numpy_support import carray, farray, from_dtype

File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/__init__.py:3
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
----> 3 from numba.np.ufunc.decorators import Vectorize, GUVectorize, vectorize, guvectorize
      4 from numba.np.ufunc._internal import PyUFunc_None, PyUFunc_Zero, PyUFunc_One
      5 from numba.np.ufunc import _internal, array_exprs

File /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/decorators.py:3
      1 import inspect
----> 3 from numba.np.ufunc import _internal
      4 from numba.np.ufunc.parallel import ParallelUFuncBuilder, ParallelGUFuncBuilder
      6 from numba.core.registry import DelayedRegistry

SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception
```

Comment: Have you [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SystemError%3A+initialization+of+_internal+failed+without+raising+an+exception) for this problem on Stack Overflow and studied the existing solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I can not guess what exactly causes your problem, but I faced same issue using Google Colab. Downgrading versions helped (`numba`):

```
!pip uninstall -y orbax flax dopamine-rl
!pip install "numba<=0.56.0"
!pip install librosa==0.9.2 timit-utils==0.9.0 torchaudio
```

Then I clicked **'Restart runtime'** button.

Comment: really helped: 'pip3 uninstall numba && pip3 install numba==0.56.4'